# Got a CS1061 error when build microsoft bot sample code

Tags: c#, bots

I got a CS1061 error when I try to build a Microsoft bot sample code, here is the web document contain whole class, http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/dialogs.html

and the error occur in

```
var parser = new Chronic.Parser();
var span = parser.Parse(date.Entity + " " + time.Entity);

if (span != null) {
    var when = span.Start ?? span.End;
    var alarm = new Alarm() { What = title.Entity, When = when.Value };
    this.alarmByWhat[alarm.What] = alarm;
    string reply = $"alarm {alarm} created";
    await context.PostAsync(reply);
}
```

> CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Start' and no extension method 'Start' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Well, does it contain member called `Start`?

Comment: none, span is an object without Start member. I just wandering how to make it working.